# Matching groups in regex

Tags: java, regex

I wanted to match 2 groups using regex from the following Strings:

- `LyraCalSWC20161203.png`
- `LyraL4C20180302.png`

This is the regex I proposed - `Lyra([A-Za-z]{3,6})+(\\d{8}).*`

It should match 2 groups. The first one being `L4C` or `CalSWC` and the second group the date string which is 8 numbers.

I can get one group to work e.g) `LyraL4C(\\d{8}).*` but not the one to handle both variations.

Any help much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Try `Lyra(\\w+)(\\d{8}).*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use the generic `\w` selector picking all the words characters to match both versions of your samples

```
^Lyra(\w{3,6})(\d{8})\.png$
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/IO9Yky/2)

Escaped for [java](/questions/tagged/java) `^Lyra(\\w{3,6})(\\d{8})\\.png$`

Answer (score 3):

- Your pattern `Lyra([A-Za-z]{3,6})+(\\d{8}).*` is pretty good, but you miss that `L4C` contains not only letters, but also numbers.
- Next to that you also specified that the first group has between 3 and 6 elements `{3,6}` so don't need to use `+`

So you need `Lyra([A-Za-z0-9]{3,6})(\\d{8}).*`

[*See Regex demo*](https://regex101.com/r/73ZOvH/2)

Comment: The one-or-more operator can be omitted, so instead of:
`Lyra([A-Za-z0-9]{3,6})+(\\d{8}).*`

Use:
`Lyra([A-Za-z0-9]{3,6})(\\d{8}).*`